# How to print a list without square brackets?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I need to print a list in java. This is the way I know to print it:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DoubleArray {
    private List<List<Double>> listOfArray;
    public void createArray() {
        ConeCurve obj = new ConeCurve();
        int rows = (int) (((obj.getMaxX()) - (obj.getMinX())) / (obj.getStepSize()) + 1);
        int columns = (int) (((obj.getMaxY()) - (obj.getMinY())) / (obj.getStepSize()) + 1);
        double x = obj.getMinX();
        double y = obj.getMinY();

        listOfArray = new ArrayList<>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            listOfArray.add(new ArrayList<>(columns));
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            x = obj.getMinX();
            for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
                listOfArray.get(column).add(obj.getZ(x, y));
                x += obj.getStepSize();
            }
            y = y + obj.getStepSize();
        }
    }

    public void printArray() {
        for (List<Double> element : listOfArray) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is fine but it is in the form `[ output....]`.
The name and format of the method must not be changed. I am trying to print the list without the `[]` (square) brackets. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

I uploaded the full code, the obj is only used to call values from a different class.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't print the [...] brackets. The only way it would do that is if the List contained an array which I suspect it might given its name (`listOfArray`).

Comment: I guess you can use `listOfArray.stream().forEach(String::toString())`

Comment: Ya it is an ArrayList

Comment: listOfArray is a 2D arrayList. What kind of format is expected?

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(element);` prints a List.  All List implementations in Java SE inherit the toString() method of AbstractCollection, whose [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) states:

> The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets (`"[]"`). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters `", "` (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by `String.valueOf(Object)`.

Instead of relying on the default toString() method of the `element` List, join that List’s elements yourself:

```
System.out.println(
    element.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(
        Collectors.joining(", ")));
```